# Design Pattern for orchestration

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have three java component - `ComponentA,` `ComponentB,` `ComponentC`. I want to orchestrate these component. There could be multiple combination (but in sequence) while executing these component for e.g. `ComponentA,` -> `ComponentB,` -> `ComponentC` or `ComponentA,` -> `ComponentC`. Which pattern would be the best fit here ? Every component has their own functionality and doesn't depend on each other. I'm looking at mediator java pattern but not sure if this is good fit in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern might fit for this scenario.

Comment: In COR, if the request cannot be handled by a component then only it goes to next in command. But in this case, OP wants it to pass through all the components. So, a pipeline or state pattern might be well suited.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with complex Objects in your Components and specific Data_flow, you can try to implement the logical model of [Pipeline_software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)). It'll give you great control of your process. In order to be more specific I can recommend you the [Pipes & filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx) (Although it's from MSDN you can still use it's design).

- Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the below

```
orchestra-tor -> component1 -> returns to orchestra-tor
orchestra-tor -> component2 -> returns to orchestra-tor
orchestra-tor -> component3 -> returns to orchestra-tor
```

This way, you may choose to skip a component or introduce business logic btw the components later

Answer (score 1):

The [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern may be work to play the components actions in sequence. As the link states, is used to wizards, that is a sequence of screens, or macro recording, a sequence of commands. Here we are talking of a sequence of executions, that's why maybe applies.

I found [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm) implementation related to your question.